# Explaining a string trimming function

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14

I came across the code below but need some help with understanding the code.  Assume that the string s has spaces either side.

```
string trim(string const& s){
   auto front = find_if_not(begin(s), end(s), isspace);
   auto back = find_if_not(rbegin(s), rend(s), isspace);
   return string { front, back.base() };
}
```

The author stated that back points to the end of the last space whereas the front points to the first non-white space character.  So **back.base()** was called but I don't understand why.

Also what do the curly braces, following string in the return statement, represent?

Comment: Short of profiling the whole thing, this actually looks like a neat piece of code.

Comment: This code will crash on inputs consisting of only one or more whitespace characters, because the iterators will cross.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I concur. it needs a safety valve to ensure `back.base()` is greater than `front`, otherwise just return empty-string.  I still like the idea in principal. I think it will actually throw an length exception because the result of `last` - `first` will be negative.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The braces are the new C++11 initialisation.

**`.base()` and reverse iterators**

The `.base()` is to get back the the underlying iterator (`back` is a `reverse_iterator`), to properly construct the new string from a valid range.

A picture. Normal iterator positions of a string (it is a little more complex than this regarding how `rend()` works, but conceptually anyway...)

```
        begin                                 end
          v                                    v
        -------------------------------------
        | sp | sp | A | B | C | D | sp | sp |
        -------------------------------------
      ^                                   ^
    rend                                rbegin
```

Once your two find loops finish, the result of those iterators in this sequence will be positioned at:

```
                  front
                    v
        -------------------------------------
        | sp | sp | A | B | C | D | sp | sp |
        -------------------------------------
                                ^
                              back
```

Were we to take just those iterators and construct a sequence from them (which we can't, as they're not matching types, but regardless, supposed we could), the result would be "copy starting at A, stopping at D" **but it would not include D in the resulting data**.

Enter the `back()` member of a reverse iterator. It returns a non-reverse iterator of the forward iterator class, that is positioned at the element "next to" the back iterator; i.e.

```
                  front
                    v
        -------------------------------------
        | sp | sp | A | B | C | D | sp | sp |
        -------------------------------------
                                    ^
                               back.base()
```

*Now* when we copy our range `{ front, back.base() }` we copy starting at `A` and stopping at the first space (but not including it), thereby including the D we would have missed.

Its actually a slick little piece of code, btw.

**Some additional checking**

Added some basic checks to the original code.

In trying to keeping with the spirit of the original code (C++1y/C++14 usage), adding some basic checks for empty and white space only strings;

```
string trim_check(string const& s)
{
  auto is_space = [](char c) { return isspace(c, locale()); };
  auto front = find_if_not(begin(s), end(s), is_space);
  auto back = find_if_not(rbegin(s), make_reverse_iterator(front), is_space);
  return string { front, back.base() };
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting the `base()` iterator references the element *next to* that referenced by the reverse iterator. In this case, somewhat synonymous to `std::next(back)`, but not in the reverse direction, rather in the "forward" direction of the underlying sequence.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. As an additional reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator contains a nice write up on the `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but why does front point to the first non-whitespace char but back does not point to the last non-space char?

Comment: @Smithy `back` *does* reference the last none-whitespace character. But if you include that as the `end` iterator of a copy (or in your case, an iterator-range constructor) that is the *stopping* position and you're one slot *short* (and its the wrong type iterator anyway). You don't want to stop there, you want to stop one "slot" *after* that position. Think of it similar to how `end()` in a normal iterator sequences references "one-past" the last element. Remember, in C++ iterator end points mean stop when you "get here", not stop once you "pass here". I hope that made sense.

Comment: My ascii-art is pretty lame, but I hope that brings a picture to to this answer (=1 btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks for the artwork. The more I look at it, the more I agree, it is a pretty neat piece of code.

Comment: @WhozCraig There should be a badge for such edits. +3 to random answers of yours (and +1 here)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your clear explanation. Now I get it. Thanks to all who helped out.

Comment: How is the lambda better than calling ::isspace directly ?

Comment: @Chnossos To be frank, in practice, not a massive difference, this is often how it is done. The theory relates to the conversion from char to int for `int isspace(int ch)` which requires a the `ch` to be representable as  `unsigned char` http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace. The lambda avoids the conversion (which could technically cause undefined behaviour, although I've seen this UB argued at great length) and the lambda uses the "nicer" C++ `isspace(char, locale)`. My personal preference is to use the C++ facilities over the C ones where they exist, but it is just personal.

Comment: @Niall I see. Isn't there a way to disambiguate directly (since the one with the locale seems to be templated) ? Also, please note that this code doesn't compile as is. `rbegin()` for instance does not exist.

Comment: @Chnossos If I understand the question, yes there is. The compiler deduces the template type as `char` from the argument supplied, so the function call becomes `isspace(char,locale)`. The C++ `isspace` with the locale requires the `locale` to bound to the call, so a simple address can't be used, this can be done with a lambda; `bind` or one of the C++98 "binders" (`bind2nd` etc.). Good point, the `rbegin` is a library facility that will be introduced with C++14, some libraries already implement it. Since the original code had it, I've keep it in the sample.

Comment: Why is `<decltype(front)>` needed?

Comment: @Yakk, just to get the type for the reverse iterator template, you could type it out, but since auto was used, I just used the decltype as well.